# AWS RDS Aurora MySQL multi regions write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an EKS cluster in a region connected to RDS Mysql, now i want to have another cluster in another region for High availability, i want MySQL to be replicated cross regions, while each region support write to its MySQL instance, i converted the database into Aurora MySQL,created global database, but i cannot create write instance in the second region, simply how can i get both databases at both regions replicated. while each of them is supporting writing to, [image: Current rds seting]

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html):

> An Aurora global database consists of one *primary* AWS Region where your data is written, and up to five read-only *secondary* AWS Regions.

You can configure [Write Forwarding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database-write-forwarding.html) so that your application can send writes to the read-only instances:

> With write forwarding enabled, secondary clusters in an Aurora global database forward SQL statements that perform write operations to the primary cluster. The primary cluster updates the source and then propagates resulting changes back to all secondary AWS Regions.

Comment: I did so, but my application still see the endpoint as read only, i can even see ro in its name.

Comment: Enabling write forwarding isn't going to cause the read-only endpoint to be renamed. It will still have `ro` in its name. Did you test sending an actual write to the endpoint?

Comment: Yes, and its still seems not working, treating it as a read only endpoint.